# $\{u_1, u_2, . . . , u_n\}$ independent $\Longrightarrow \{Bu_1, Bu_2, . . . , Bu_n\}$ independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I have no idea how to prove this:

Let
$S = \{u_1, u_2, . . . , u_n\}$, 
be a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $B \in M_{(m\times m)}(\mathbb{R})$ is invertible. Prove that the set
$L_B(S) = \{Bu_1, Bu_2, . . . , Bu_n\}$
is also linearly independent

Comment: A simpler question: do you know what "invertible" and "linearly independent" mean?

Comment: It is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\{Bu_1, Bu_2, \ldots, Bu_n\}$ is not linearly independent. Then some vector in $\{Bu_1, Bu_2, \ldots, Bu_n\}$ is a linear combination of the others. Without loss of generality, say

$$
Bu_1 = c_2 Bu_2 + c_3 Bu_3 + \cdots + c_n Bu_n
$$

Multiplying both sides by $B^{-1}$ gives

$$
u_1 = c_2 u_2 + c_3 u_3 + \cdots + c_n u_n
$$

Which means $\{u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n\}$ is linearly dependent, a contradiction. Therefore, $\{Bu_1, Bu_2, \ldots, Bu_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The first two steps of most exercise-proofs are the same.

1. Suppose $u_1,\ldots,u_n$ are linearly independent. **By the definition of "linearly independent"**, for all $k_1, \ldots, k_n$ that are not all zero, $k_1u_1 + \cdots + k_nu_n \neq 0$.
2. We wish to show $Bu_1, \ldots, Bu_n$ are linearly independent. **By the definition of linearly independent**, for any $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ not all zero, we must show $c_1Bu_1 + \cdots + c_nBu_n \neq 0$.

Can you go from there?

Answer (score 0):

Matrices and linear transformation can be seen as interchangeable. Thus an invertible matrix is a 1-1 linear transformation. That is, a bijective linear transformation (onto its range). This is a vector space isomorphism and LI sets being described in the language of vector spaces are preserved by isomorphism.